# android getPageTitle is not worked

Tags: java, android

> I am working with the FragmentPagerAdapter and have a problem with the
>   getPageTitle() method. Everythings is working but it. plz take a look at my code blowing and help me out.

```
public class MyFragmentPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;
        public final static String PAGE_CURRENT = "current_age";
        public final static String PAGE_ID = "id";
        int id = 0;

        public MyFragmentPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int id) {
            super(fm);
            this.id = id;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt(PAGE_CURRENT, position + 1);
            bundle.putInt(PAGE_ID, id);
            myFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            return myFragment;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            CharSequence title = null;
            if (position == 0) {
                title = "a";
            } else if (position == 1) {
                title = "b";
            } else if (position == 2) {
                title = "c";
            }
            return title;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return PAGE_COUNT;
        }

    }
```

> And in my main Activity i declared:

```
ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        MyFragmentPageAdapter fragmentAdapter = new MyFragmentPageAdapter(fm,
                id);
        pager.setAdapter(fragmentAdapter);
```

Comment: Can you paste your OnPageChangeListener implementation?

Comment: Hi LR89, i implemented the OnPageChangeListener and it dont call the getPageTitle() method, any help pz?

Comment: So where do you call getPageTitle() and what do you mean by "it doesn't work". Does it return null or what? Your Adapter looks fine so it should work.

Comment: Hi LR89, It is an @override  method so i think it will be called when we run the pageAdapter same the getItems(). I mean it wasn't called when i run the pager.

Comment: @Hainguyen May be you get so confuse about that function. Here, the getPageTitle() is just an override function to get the current page title (default that).
So it is based on where/when you want to show your title.
Here, you use view pager, and no reason to use it, just leave it alone.
If you use Actionbar, so you can set the selected page title by call that function.

Answer (score 0):

// try the below code

```
 public class MyFragmentPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
 protected static final String[] CONTENT = new String[] { "a", "b", "c"};
    final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;
    public final static String PAGE_CURRENT = "current_age";
    public final static String PAGE_ID = "id";
    int id = 0;

 private int mCount = CONTENT.length;

  // CHANGE STARTS HERE
  private int current_position=0;

  public void set_current_position(int i) {
    current_position = i;
  }

    public MyFragmentPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int id) {
        super(fm);
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragm`enter code here`ent();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt(PAGE_CURRENT, position + 1);
        bundle.putInt(PAGE_ID, id);
        myFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return myFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

        if (position == current_position-1) {
        return "Previous";
    } else if (position == current_position+1) {
        return "Next";
    }
    // CHANGE ENDS HERE
    return MyFragmentPageAdapter.CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length];
}


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and assume it's an Android bug. Set the page title in TabLayout.createTabAtPosition(), with this code:
`return newTab().setText("the page title");`